# Residual Analysis in R

Tags: residuals, boxplot

I am trying to develop a strategy to deal with outliers.
Below is the residual boxplot that I have generated for the test data, train data and both the test and train data.

My question is, what is the best way to deal with these outliers? Is it ok to just leave them if I had looked at them closely and there is no evidence to show that they are outliers due to mistake? What is the best way to go about this sort of problem?

Thank you!

[image]